# Select only columns from joined tables from CTE

Tags: sql-server, join, common-table-expression

The following is my CTE:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(SELECT O.*, E.Num, E.Amount 
FROM OData O
INNER JOIN Equip E
ON O.Name = E.Name)  
SELECT * FROM CTE -- gives results I want to join to
```

The following is the query that I want to `SELECT` from (and only use this `SELECT` statement for my query results:

```
SELECT 
    MU.Type
    ,MU.Num
    ,MU.MTBUR
    ,MF.MTBF
    ,MU.Hours 
    ,MF.Hours 
FROM 
    MUType_Stage MU
INNER JOIN 
    MFType_Stage MF
    ON
    MU.Type = MF.Type
    AND
    MU.Num = MF.Num
```

-- Need do `JOIN` to `CTE` right here

```
INNER JOIN 
        Status_STAGE S
        ON
        MU.Nu = S.Part
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        RCN N
        ON
        N.Name  = R.Part
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Repair RR
        ON
        R.ACSS_Name = RR.Name
```

So basically I need to `JOIN` to the `CTE` inside the `SELECT` query in which I want the results.

**OR ALTERNATIVELY**  Uses this select statement to join to the CTE but only what the selected columns from the second select statement

Comment: You've named your CTE "CTE" (which isn't very descriptive)... so just JOIN CTE ON whatever columns you need to join.  It's not clear at all from this example what those columns would be, but presumably you know.  I'm not exactly sure what your problem or question is, actually?  You say "Need to join to CTE right here"... so ... do it?  What am I missing? Just take out the "SELECT * FROM CTE " from your CTE block, and add the JOIN CTE where you've indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this syntax

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT O.*,
                E.Num,
                E.Amount
         FROM   OData O
                INNER JOIN Equip E
                        ON O.Name = E.Name)
SELECT MU.Type,
       MU.Num,
       MU.MTBUR,
       MF.MTBF,
       MU.Hours,
       MF.Hours
FROM   MUType_Stage MU
       INNER JOIN MFByACType_Stage MF
               ON MU.Type = MF.Type
                  AND MU.Num = MF.Num
       INNER JOIN CTE C --- JOIN HERE as like other tables
               ON C.Num = MF.Num
       INNER JOIN Status_STAGE S
               ON MU.Nu = S.Part
       LEFT OUTER JOIN RCN N
                    ON N.Name = R.Part
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Repair RR
                    ON R.ACSS_Name = RR.Name
```